# Mocking a Flask POST request with json arguments using pytest and pytest-mock

Tags: python, flask, pytest, pytest-mock

I want to test the input/output for a POST request with flask, and possibly mock both outcomes if possible. For simplicity, I've stripped down most of the logic.

```py
# extract.py
import app  # This is the main flask app. Just a basic setup.
from flask import jsonify, request

@app.route('/extract', methods=['POST'])
def task():
    args = request.json
    table_name = args.get('table')
    start_date = args.get('start_date')
    end_date = args.get('end_date')

    # Logic here
    result = dict(key1=value1, key2=value2)

    return jsonify(result)
```

I'm not happy with this scenario, given that everything is mocked and I can't guarantee the function will run properly. Ideally, I'd be able to pass the JSON data for the POST request, and check the response provided by the `jsonify(result)` method of `extract.py`.

```py
# test_extract.py
# mocker comes from pytest-mock


def test_trigger_extract_1(mocker):
    import extract

    mocker.patch.object(extract, 'task')

    data = [{
        'table': 'name',
        'start_date': '2020-01-02',
        'end_date': '2020-01-03',
    }]

    extract.task.return_value.status_code = 200
    extract.task.return_value.json.return_value = data

    extract.task()

    extract.task.assert_called_once()
```

The usual way I'd do this, would be to call `request.get('/extract', json=json.dumps(data))` and test against the response provided, given this would actually run the code. The thing is, I know this isn't ideal, because if the server breaks, or something else goes wrong, I won't be able to test it properly.

Comment: have you looked at the official `flask` docs which show how to test the client? https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/testing/#testing-json-apis